# ObjC method naming convention in this case?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, naming-conventions

I have a class which represents exam,it can start/reset/pause exam, so the methods look like:

```
- (void)startExam;
- (void)resetExam;
- (void)pauseExam;
```

But as far as I know, if the method name ends with some noun, it should have argument for that noun, something like:

```
- (void)startExam:(Exam *)exam;
```

But in this case, the class is named 'Exam', so when the class is used, people would know that the object is an Exam, so it seems the better way of naming is:

```
@interface Exam : NSObject
- (void)start;
- (void)reset;
- (void)pause;
@end
```

so I can use is as:

```
Exam *exam = [[[Exam alloc] init] autoreleased];
[exam start];
```

which looks better than:

```
[exam startExam];
```

or

```
[exam examStart];
```

But this does look TOO generic, and I feel risky as NSObject(or whatever super class) may have methods of the same name added in the future, for example, Java Object has notify, notifyAll, wait, and subclass should not overwrite these for other purposes. Is this also true in Objective C?

So what is the best naming convention in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start/pause/reset belong to the class `Exam`. So I would go for:

```
@interface Exam : NSObject
- (void)start;
- (void)reset;
- (void)pause;
@end
```

When I am using an object of the Class `Exam` I just read it in my head:

```
[myExam start];
```

For me makes more sense than this:

```
[myExam startExam];
```

As for the one that has an input parameter:

```
- (void)startWith:(Exam *)exam;
```

**PS:** But I could see myself doing what Dirk suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In objective C, nobody would actually expect the method `startExam` to take an argument whatsoever. This would be method `startExam:` (note the trailing colon). These are different methods, you can even have both on the same class. So, I would go for `startExam`.

Comment: I wouldn't.  Given the object that the method is being sent to an exam, the word "exam" on the end of the selector is redundant.

Comment: @JeremyP - It boils down to a matter of taste, I think. I personally find `start`, `pause`, and `reset` a little bit too generic. OTOH, if the context is as clear as it seems to be here, it doesn't really matter. Anyway, my main point was, that there is no confusion wrt. "method takes an argument" here, due to Objective-C's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> But this does look TOO generic,

Not to me it doesn't.  The word "exam" in your methods is redundant given the object models an exam.  If you see the code

```
[myExam start];
```

what else is starting apart from the exam?